# perform segue by using various view controllers and array of UIView successors

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

OK, so this one might be a little difficult to explain.

I am trying to make an app in objective c were on the first screen you can slide between pictures that describe pages, but are not actually the page.  And when you click a picture, you go to the relevant page the picture presented.

I used a very nice youtube tutorial for using the slide option with ScrollView and PageControl.
According to this tutorial you make a new class, successor of UIView named "Slide" with h., m. and xib file. 
In your MainViewController you have an array of "Slide" and you can swap between Slides.

This is the creation of the array:

```
- (NSArray*)createSlides{
    NSArray *arr;
    Slide *slide1 = (Slide*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Slide" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    slide1.label.text = @"Slide1";
    [slide1.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scratch"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    Slide *slide2 = (Slide*)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Slide" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    slide2.label.text = @"Slide2";
    [slide2.button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expose"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: slide1, slide2, nil];
    return arr;
}
```

Than in another function I use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<slides.count; ++i) {
    slides[i].frame = CGRectMake(width * (CGFloat)i, 0, width, height);
    [_slideScrollView addSubview:slides[i]];
}
```

(This is not all of it, but I'm not sure the other parts of the code are relevant for my question.).

So far so good. It works perfectly.

Now, I want to add the functionality of clicking the picture and perform segue to the relevant view controller. For example, I have "ExposeViewController" for slide2.
The problem is that I click the picture on "Slide" but I perform the segue from the MainViewController.

At first I tried to make UIButton on Slide class (that shows the relevant picture) and to create a  button action which somehow detect the Slide's (UIView's) ViewController, pass it somehow the name of the segue identifier and than in a method of the view controller to perform the segue.

It didn't work and I didn't like this solution.

After few hours of research i'm still not sure how to make it.
How can I make user press on button that is part of UIView (Slide) perform method in it's view controller to go to another view controller?

Comment: You can try the tap gesture instead of button actions

Comment: But the tap gesture would still be in the xib file.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the different tag to each button like this.

```
Slide1.button.tag = 1
```

`Slide2.button.tag = 2`

Then add same custom action to each button like

```
 [Slide1.button addTarget:self action:@selector(functionName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[Slide2.button addTarget:self action:@selector(functionName:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now we create the selector function manually like this-

```
-(void) functionName:(UIButton*) sender{
If (sender.tag == 1){
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"//firstIdentifier" sender:self]; }
else If (sender.tag == 2) {
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"//secondIdentifier" sender:self]; }
}
```

Where you need to check the particular tag of Sender button and perform the action accordingly.

Comment: can you please expand you answer?

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I did. but for some reason the selector leads me to "slide.functionName" and not to the "mainViewController.functionName" and I get an exception

Comment: @OfirKariv you are writing the func in your mainviewController right?  And have you created the same func name in your slide class?

Comment: @shibi_shub I added answer with example